# Unable to create user namespace in RHEL

Tags: linux, rhel, docker, namespace

I'm trying to create user namespace in RHEL 7 but unable to because of the below error:

```
[root@teja7131 ~]# unshare -U /bin/bash
unshare: unshare failed: Invalid argument
```

Please explain the correct argument format for creating the user namespace.

Comment: "Invalid argument" here almost certainly does not refer to the command line you entered, but rather, an argument that the command you're invoking is passing to the kernel for the `unshare` system call. Check `dmesg` for a possible clue. This might also be distribution-specific, so perhaps vendor-provided resources would be a better avenue of research.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If one uses `strace` to inspect the command

```
$ strace -o logf -f unshare -U sh
unshare: unshare failed: Invalid argument
$ grep 'Invalid argument' logf
31728 unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER)            = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
31728 write(2, "Invalid argument\n", 17) = 17
```

this reveals that the system call `unshare(2)` has failed. Notably `CLONE_NEWUSER` does not appear in the manual page, which could be a documentation bug or could indicate that `CLONE_NEWUSER` is not supported on a stock install of RedHat 7 (I'm using Centos7 here on a test system, which is similar to but different from RedHat 7).

```
$ man 2 unshare | col -b | grep CLONE_NEWUSER
$
```

This is strange; altagoobingleduckgoing the terms `unshare` and `CLONE_NEWUSER` yields [questions about `unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103994/why-unshareclone-newuser-return-error-linux) though from that `CONFIG_USER_NS` is apparently enabled on Centos 7:

```
$ grep CONFIG_USER_NS /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_USER_NS=y
```

Yet more altagoobingleduckgoing turns up an [lxc thread](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/842) that indicates that "Currently user namespaces are in TECH PREVIEW phase" (as of RedHat 7.2) so may or may not work. Adding `user_namespace.enable=1` to the kernel arguments did not help on my Centos 7.5 system (and is not necessary in testing, below). The [Kernel features page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_administration_guide/kernel_features#supported_namespaces) however lists user namespaces as supported; Filipe Brandenburger found [is it safe to enable user namespaces](https://superuser.com/questions/1294215/is-it-safe-to-enable-user-namespaces-in-centos-7-4-and-how-to-do-it/1294246#1294246) which indicates that by default RedHat 7 enables 0 namespaces for users, though this number can be increased:

```
# cat /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces
0
# echo 640 > /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces
# unshare -U sh
sh-4.2$
```

So increasing `max_user_namespaces` on Centos 7.5 works, and does not require the `user_namespace.enable=1` kernel flag.

Even more reading:

https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/07/07/whats-next-for-containers-user-namespaces/

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/a/1294246/879179, perhaps you need to tweak `/proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces` as well on recent RHEL 7 kernels.

Comment: Apparently this is enabled by default starting with RHEL 8: https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_8/2021-12-03/finding/V-230548